# How do I delete all blank lines in a buffer?

Tags: text-editing

Emacs 26.1

In buffer

```
1


2


3


4
```

I use command "`delete-blank-lines`". But it NOT delete ALL BLANK LINES. It's delete ONLY ONE BLANK LINE.

Why?

I need to delete ALL BLANK LINES.
The result must be like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Are you saying you used `delete-blank-lines` once? If you look at the help for the function, it will tell you it deletes the *surrounding* blank lines, that is the blank lines around point, not all blank lines in the buffer.

Comment: What @WillyLee said.

Comment: See also: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/41636/105. The question has been asked more than once, expressed in different ways.

Answer (score 20):

From [MasteringEmacs.com](https://masteringemacs.org/article/removing-blank-lines-buffer) By Mickey Petersen:

> This is a frequent question so I figured I’d mention the solution here:
>
> You want to remove all empty (blank) lines from a buffer. How do you do it? Well, it’s super easy.
>
> Mark what you want to change (or use `C-x h` to mark the whole buffer) and run this:
>
> `M-x flush-lines RET ^$ RET`
>
> And you’re done. So what does that mean? Well, `M-x flush-lines` will flush (remove) lines that match a regular expression, and ^$ contain the meta-characters ^ for beginning of string and $ for end of string. Ergo, if the two meta-characters are next to eachother, it must be a blank line.
>
> We can also generalize it further and remove lines that may have whitespace (only!) characters:
>
> `M-x flush-lines RET ^\s-*$ RET`
>
> In this case `\s-` is the syntax class (type `C-h s` to see your buffer’s syntax table) for whitespace characters. The `*` meta-character, in case you are not a regexp person, means zero or more of the preceding character.

Comment: This help me:  M-x flush-lines ^$