# flush-lines fails in script but works when called otherwise

Tags: regular-expressions, backslash

I'm very new to programming in Elisp so maybe the mistake is there but I'm completely stuck right now.

I wanted to make a small, simple Elisp function to remove the AUTOs from my Verilog files so I don't commit those lines to our git repository since the rest of my team doesn't use Emacs. I thought this would be a very simple task but for the life of me, I can't get `flush-lines` to work properly.

The regular expression I'm trying to use is `\/\*AUTO\w+\*/`. When I do `M-x flush-lines RET \/\*AUTO\w+\*/ RET` this works. So I would think the regular expression works. But when I try to do it in either my .emacs or by doing `M-: (flush-lines "\/\*AUTO\w+\*/" nil (buffer-size) t) RET`, it just outputs a `nil`. I also tried `(flush-lines "\/\*AUTO\w+\*/")` and `(flush-lines "\/\*AUTO\w+\*/" nil (buffer-size))` and they both just output `nil` and don't remove the matching lines. My point is set to the top of the buffer, so I don't understand what the issue is. I can't seem to find anywhere any resources that could point me in the right direction. The closest I found was [this post from a couple years ago](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41636/how-to-use-flush-lines-in-a-script) but it goes far beyond the simple task I'm trying to do, and I seem to be suffering from a different issue than that user was.

Comment: After successfully completing your interactive command, you can try `M-x command-history` to see what Emacs thinks you did in Elisp terms.  In your case, it shows the command as
`(flush-lines "\\/\\*AUTO\\w+\\*/" nil nil t)`

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @gregoryg: Please consider developing your comment into an answer. Bonus points for linking to the doc (about doubling backslashes in Lisp).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [re-search-forward Regex behavior for OR boolean](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55601/re-search-forward-regex-behavior-for-or-boolean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for escaping elements of regular expressions can be confusing.

Once you find an interactive solution that works, a handy tip is to look at Emacs' command history:

```
M-x command-history
```

With the command given in the question, the command history shows:

```el
(flush-lines "\\/\\*AUTO\\w+\\*/" nil nil t)
```

That gives the Elisp that will work.  The reason all the extra escaping is necessary can be found in the following doc:
[Special Characters in Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html#Regexp-Special)

The character `\` has special meaning both in regexp and in the Lisp reader.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!